# Why generated signature by "Digital signature algorithm (SHA-256)" with CMS is not valid in my partner

Tags: c#, http, digital-signature, x509certificate2, cryptographic-hash-function

I have big problem with signature I don't recognized why it's not work.

I want to use AS2 over http with digital signature.

Minimal Story:

I generated private key, certificate and as result .pfx file by following commands:

`openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048`

`openssl req -new -sha256 -key key.pem -out csr.csr`

`openssl x509 -req -in csr.csr -signkey key.pem -out cert.crt`

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -inkey key.pem -out certificate.p12`

And firstly I just tried

1. hash my "data" by sha256
2. sign data with rsa.

When I had sent it, I encountered an error. Error that not recognized hash algorithm.

Question: this error mean that I must use "RFC 6211 - Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)"?

And next I tried this c# code:

```
public byte[] SignData(byte[] data, string p12FilePath, string p12Password)
 {
     X509Certificate2 signingCert = new X509Certificate2(p12FilePath, p12Password);

     ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);

     SignedCms signedMessage = new SignedCms(content, false);

     CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, signingCert);

     signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid(Oid.FromFriendlyName("SHA256", OidGroup.HashAlgorithm));
     signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;

     signedMessage.ComputeSignature(signer);

     byte[] signedBytes = signedMessage.Encode();

     return signedBytes;
 }
```

After that I load data to my http and as result it's have this http format:

```
 // Create multipart form data
 string boundary = "STARTBOUND_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_ENDBOUND";

  var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary)
  {
      Headers =
      {
          ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/signed")
          {
              Parameters =
              {
                  new NameValueHeaderValue("boundary", boundary),
                  new NameValueHeaderValue("protocol", "\"application/pkcs7-signature\""),
                  new NameValueHeaderValue("micalg", "sha1")
              }
          },
      }
  };


 var fileContentPart = new ByteArrayContent(as2Message);
 fileContentPart.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/EDIFACT");
 fileContentPart.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
 fileContentPart.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
 {
     FileName = "data.edifact"
 };
 formData.Add(fileContentPart);



 var signatureData = SignData(as2Message, _PathToMyPrivateKey, _Passphrase);



 var signatureContentPart = new StringContent(Convert.ToBase64String(signatureData));

 signatureContentPart.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pkcs7-signature");
 signatureContentPart.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("name", "smime.p7s"));
 signatureContentPart.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("smime-type", "signed-data"));

 signatureContentPart.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");

 signatureContentPart.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
 {
     FileName = "smime.p7s"
 };
 formData.Add(signatureContentPart);
```

When I had sent it I received another error: Outbound MDN details: Error verifying the senders digital signature: Verification failed

I 1000 times checked my certificates and all is correct.
My partner tried add this certificate (which I sended to him) to Trusted Certificates store, but it's not helped us.
But I don't understand why this error.

In internet I searched that exist

1. Signature
2. CMS with Sinature (Please explain me one thing: Can I create CMS from scratch? and where example of it. Because in rfc I have only this

```
" SignerInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
           version CMSVersion,
           sid SignerIdentifier,
           digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier,
           signedAttrs [0] IMPLICIT SignedAttributes OPTIONAL,
           signatureAlgorithm SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier,
           signature SignatureValue,
           unsignedAttrs [1] IMPLICIT UnsignedAttributes OPTIONAL }"
```

)

My partner has "Use "Algorithm Identifier Protection Attribute" in signature "in Mendelson and SHA-256 algo to digital signature algorithm What it's mean?

Please give me some help)

Comment: Try running without form data in body and see if you still get an error.  The signature on the multipart may be the issue and removing the body will help determine if error is on the signature or the body data.

Comment: @jdweng I tried it's not work). Tried to write application/pkcs7-signature as content-type
as params to content type: "smime-type", "signed-data"; "name", "smime.p7s" and I have another error) 

state set to [processed/error: insufficient-message-security].
Incoming messages from AS2 partner AS2Ident are defined to be signed.

And in mendelson gui in section Signature "No signature"

Comment: Has your partner ever signed a multipart?  You have MIME (multi-part) where each part starts with two dashes on a new line (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)).  Do you think this applies :  https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Provider-Enrollment-and-Certification/MedicareProviderSupEnroll/Downloads/E-SignatureHowToGuide.pdf

Comment: I found where was my fail. I have to generate CMS signature from all section in my boundary) 
If I have ---boundary---/r/n Content-Type:abc; /r/n/r/n my tekst /r/n---boundary--
I need to get CMS signature from "/r/n Content-Type:abc; /r/n/r/n my tekst /r/n")
@jdweng thanks for help)

Comment: The issue was the MIME.